# error 1004 método select clase range en un sólo excel, en otros pcs con el mismo excel funciona sin problemas

Tags: excel

este codigo funciona en 2 ordenadores con la misma versió de excel, en el mio no, mirando veo este código que da error 1004 en tiempo de ejecucion, error en el metodo Select de la clase Range.

```
Sub Ordenar()
'
' Ordenar Macro
'

'

    Range("DADES[#All]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dades").ListObjects("DADES").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dades").ListObjects("DADES").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("DADES[Clients]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dades").ListObjects("DADES").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: mensaje de error]
[image: linia error]

Comment: Hola. Agrega el mensaje de error a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Ya lo tienes pegado, gracias.

Comment: [Verifica aquí](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-1004-error/) los diferentes motivos por los que el error 1004 puede ocurrir.

Comment: Gracias pero no se soluciona, yo no sé programar, lo siento pero veo que si hago foco en la hoja "Dades" entonces no da el error, lo que no sé es como hacer que sea la hoja activa por así decirlo

Comment: Antes de esa línea, si la hoja se llama `Dades`. prueba añadiendo `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Dades").Activate` Pero es raro que en unos funcione y otros no. ¿Tenéis todos la misma versión de Excel? ¿Mismo sistema operativo? ¿Misma configuración de idioma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

las soluciones que planteáis las aplicamos antes de publicar la pregunta pero siempre me asaltaba la duda, ¿porque en otros equipos si y en el mío no? la solución era "sencilla", un bug de Office al instalarse en las últimas versiones (2013,2016 y 365) provoca que una dll NO se instale ni registre, MSCOMCT2.OCX. Esta dll es para tener el control date & time en Excel, sin él NO funciona la programación que lo tenga incorporado, para solucionarlo seguir el link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6f8832d-5ad7-4192-bc72-b3b6fdcc46ee/datepicker-in-excel-2013-32-bit-running-on-win-81-64-bit?forum=exceldev
Funciona en Windows 10, revisad por eso la versión (32/64bits) de office y Windows antes de hacerlo y acordaros de ejecutar el CMD con derechos de administrador.

Gracias de nuevo a tod@s!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido!

El comando que arroja el error procura seleccionar el rango entero (incluyendo cabecera) de una tabla llamada "DADES".
Sin embargo, puede ser que la pestaña activa (al momento de la ejecución del comando) no sea la pestaña que contiene dicha tabla, y por eso te arroja el error.

Puedes agregar el siguiente comando en la línea superior, de esta manera forzarás la Hoja de cálculo a Seleccionar la pestaña (como quiera que se llame) donde se encuentre la Tabla "DADES"

```
Range("DADES[#All]").Worksheet.Select
```

y una vez activa podrá ejecutar el comando sin errores.
Cuéntame cómo te fue!
Saludos